# Overriding non-function class members in D

Tags: class, inheritance, d

Is there a way, in DLang, to override class fields that aren't functions in a derived class? Or do class vtables only contain function pointers?

For instance, I'd like the following to print "bar", but it prints "foo".

```
class Foo
{
   string s = "foo";
}

class Bar : Foo
{
   string s = "bar";
}

void main()
{
   import std.stdio;

   Foo bar = new Bar;
   writeln(bar.s);
}
```

Comment: I belive the closest thing you would get to this are properties, but they're of course functions. There is no way to override a field and it doesn't make much sense if you think about how the data is actually stored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only functions can be virtual. The vtable provides a way to look up the correct override for a function, but the variables are accessed directly without any indirections like you get when using a virtual table.

If you want to do something similar to overriding a member variable, then the closest you're going to get is a property function. e.g.

```
class Foo
{
    @property string s() { return _s; }

    private string _s = "foo";
}

class Bar : Foo
{
    override @property string s() { return _s; }

    private string _s = "bar";
}

void main()
{
    import std.stdio;

    Foo bar = new Bar;
    writeln(bar.s);
}
```